# What does Angular refreshView method do behind the scenes?

Tags: angular, performance, google-chrome-devtools

I have a list of 2000 elements displayed as a table (with virtual scrolling). I noticed it takes a lot of time for the view to update if I zoom in / out or if I resize the browser window.

I found the cause, it's a tooltip I have set on each cell, but, the problem is that using the performance profiling from Dev Tools does not indicate that's the problem.

The only thing I can see is that a method, **refreshView**, from angular/core slows down the app. Do you have any idea about what this method actually does or how could I identify what exactly makes that method to run so slow?

If I expand it I see:

```
refreshView
----refreshEmbeddedViews
     ----refreshView
         -----refreshEmbeddedViews
              ----so on
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had virtual scrolling you wouldn't have this issue. You should check that it works correctly.

The method "refreshView" is what Angular uses to detect changes in your app.

Based on your description of the issue, I would say that you have somewhere a listener that listens to window resizing and updates the view accordingly.

If you want to resolve the issue, on this listener, add a `debounceTime` operator, or use `onPush` strategy to detect changes in your app.

Or again, find other solutions for your feature, such as pagination or a working virtual scroll.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The list renders perfectly and fast without the tooltip on each cell. So the virtual scroll is working. I was asking if I could have found somehow using the profiler that the tooltip is the problem. Because I found it by commenting different parts of the code and then running again. And that tooltip it's somehow part of the refreshView but as the method does not give me any detail there is no way to debug it.